# More than nine devices can not be connected to Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) via USB cable

Tags: drivers

I am trying to connect 14 devices, but it shows only nine devices connected. If I disconnected one out of nine devices connected, another one from remaining disconnected devices shows as connected or shows charging in devices.

Is there a limit in Ubuntu related to the number of connected devices?

Comment: A single USB hub itself should be able to support up to 127 devices, so there's no specific limit aside from how USB works. What type of devices are you connecting ? It's possible that some of them require too much power , perhaps

Comment: After searching on web I found that xhci (USB 3.0) are not working properly with Ubuntu so i switched to another computer having only uhci (port usb 2.0).Now all devices connected to this computer. Is there any command for disable xhci so that all usb port behave like usb 2.0

Comment: Can you provide a link to where it says that USB 3.0 doesn't work properly with Ubuntu?